# Create regular backups from OS X to the cloud

Tags: python, django, macos

I'm developing a Django project on my MacBook Pro. Constantly paranoid that if my house burns down, someone stoling my MB, hard drive failure or another things that are not likely, but catastrophic if it occurs.

How can I create or get automatic backup every 1 hour from my OS X directory where the Django project is to a service like Dropbox or whatever cloud hosting company there might be a solution for.

Is there a Python script that does this? I can't be the only one that has thought of this before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what version control is for. Sign up for an account at Github, Bitbucket, or Gitlab, and push your code there.